# fft2 in Matlab with a dicom images (MRI)

Tags: matlab, fft, dicom, type-conversion

I want to perform a 2 dimensional fourier transform on an image slice of a cranial MRI.
I have tried the following codes and have not been successful: (*error messages included below*)

```
>> clear all
>> 
>> info = dicominfo('MR000026.dcm');
Y = dicomread(info);
J=imadjust(Y,stretchlim(Y),[0 1]);
F = fftshift(fft2(fftshift(J)));
Undefined function 'fftn' for input arguments of type 'int16'.

Error in fft2 (line 19)
        f = fftn(x);

>> info = dicominfo('MR000026.dcm');
Y = dicomread(info);
F = fftshift(fft2(fftshift(Y)));
Undefined function 'fftn' for input arguments of type 'int16'.

Error in fft2 (line 19)
        f = fftn(x);

>> info = dicominfo('MR000026.dcm');
Y = dicomread(info);
F = fft2(Y);
Undefined function 'fftn' for input arguments of type 'int16'.

Error in fft2 (line 19)
        f = fftn(x);
```

> > 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message you got says it all: `fft2` is not meant to work with `uint16` input type.
Convert Y to `double` before you process it:

```
Y = im2double( Y );
```

or even just

```
Y = double( Y );
```